# Query regarding Srardham on same thithi for Father and grandmother (mother's mom)

Tags: rituals, sraddha

I have question regarding Srardham

My father expired on 2020 May 25 (Thrithiyai) thithi. One year later my Grandmother (mother's mom) died exactly on the same thithi 2021 Jun 13th (Thrithiyai). My mom doesn't have any brother and my grandmother was all through my life taking care of me. So I am Kartha for my grandmother as well.

So last year 2022 - I did abdheekam for my grandmother and srardham for my dad

This year 2023 - there is confusion whether I can do both the srardhams on the same day? Our Sastrigal has suggested two options

1. I can do Srardham (with homam) for my dad and Hiranya srardham for my grandmother as Pitru sesham for my dad gets completed only when I eat sesham food, which means I can't do Srardham (with homam for my grandmother).
2. I can do Srardham (with homam) for my dad on Thrithiyai and do Srardham (with homam) for my grandmother during Krishna Paksha ekadashi.

Kindly suggest if there are any other suggestions?